# Adding custom functionality to django router methods

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to add custom functionality to django router methods.

This is my router that exposes the standard methods on an user.

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    permission_classes = [BasePermission]
```

I'm validating the user using serializer validation methods.

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)
    MOBILE_ERROR = 'Mobile number should be 10 digits long and only contain numbers.'
    EMAIL_ERROR = 'Incorrect email format'
    USERNAME_ERROR = 'Username must be at least 6 characters long and contain only letters and numbers.'

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'

    def validate_mobile(self, value):
        regexp = re.compile(r'^[0-9]{10}$')
        if regexp.search(value):
            return value
        raise serializers.ValidationError(self.MOBILE_ERROR)

    def validate_email(self, value):
        if validate_email(value):
            return value
        raise serializers.ValidationError(self.EMAIL_ERROR)

    def validate_username(self, value):
        regexp = re.compile(r'^[a-zA-Z0-9]{6,}$')
        if regexp.search(value):
            return value
        raise serializers.ValidationError(self.USERNAME_ERROR)
```

And this is my route.

```
router = DefaultRouter(trailing_slash=False)
router.register(r'user', UserViewSet),
urlpatterns = router.urls
```

I want to add a method `send_activation_code` if the user is created successfully. How do I do this?

Comment: could you please refer this doc with the title 'Routing for extra actions' .https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#usage ,

Answer (score 1):

For such purpose you can use signals. Every time when your app creates new `User` instance - some action should be performed. In your case you should connect build-in signal `post_save` and your existed `send_activation_code` function

Example for your case:

**yourapp/signals.py:**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def send_activation_code_signal(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        send_activation_code(instance.phone_number)
```

Also, you need to import signals in your app config file

**yourapp/app.py:**

```
from django.apps import AppConfig
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

class YourAppConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'yourproject.yourapp'
    verbose_name = _('yourapp')

    def ready(self):
        import yourproject.yourapp.signals
```

**yourapp/__init__.py:**

```
default_app_config = 'yourproject.yourapp.apps.YourAppConfig'
```

If you dont need to send code every time User instance created - you can specify more statements, for example:

```
if created and instance.validated:
    send_activation_code(instance.phone_number)
```

There are some more useful built-in signals in Django, check docs
Django signals docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/signals/